# Store result of function applications in a tuple inside a DO-block

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, do-notation

While I can apply a function two times and bind result in a tuple:

```
  let foo :: Num a => a -> a
      foo x = x + 1

  let (x,y) = (foo 10, foo 20)
```

This can't be done (ar at least I don't know how to do it properly) within a `do` block:

```
  let bar :: Num a => a -> IO a
      bar x = do
                  let y = x + 1
                  return y

  let test :: Num a => IO a
      test = do
                 (x,y) <- (bar 10, bar 20)
                 return y
```

I got the following error when typing it GHCI REPL:

```
:29:15:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘IO a1’ with actual type ‘(t0, a)’
    Relevant bindings include
      test :: IO a (bound at :28:5)
    In the pattern: (x, y)
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: (x, y) <- (bar 10, bar 20)
    In the expression:
      do { (x, y) <- (bar 10, bar 20);
           return y }

:29:24:
    Couldn't match type ‘(,) (IO a0)’ with ‘IO’
    Expected type: IO (IO a1)
      Actual type: (IO a0, IO a1)
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: (x, y) <- (bar 10, bar 20)
    In the expression:
      do { (x, y) <- (bar 10, bar 20);
           return y }
    In an equation for ‘test’:
        test
          = do { (x, y) <- (bar 10, bar 20);
                 return y }
```

I can obviously solve it with a more verbose:

```
  let test' :: Num a => IO a
      test' = do
                 x <- bar 10
                 y <- bar 20
                 return y
```

Is there a correct way to express `test` without making it like `test'`?

Comment: monadic operations work on `m (a,b)`, nothing suggests they should work on `(m a, m b)` values too — tuples are regular values of tuple types; whereas there's some special, non-generic syntactic sugar for constructing them, tuples are _not_ syntactic structures, so there's not reason why `(m a, m b)` could be directly used with `>>=`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
import Control.Applicative

test = do (x,y) <- (,) <$> bar 10 <*> bar 20
          return y
```

Aka `(x,y) <- liftA2(,) (bar 10) (bar 20)`.

Of course, for this specific example (where `x` is just thrown away) it would be equivalent and much better to just write

```
test = bar 20
```

Comment: +1 and this answers. I'm learning Haskell and sometimes I forgot that also tuple constructor `(,)` is a function. Thanks for terse sample. Yes in my question `x` is thrown away, but not in real code.

Answer (score 6):

I will take the freedom to suggest a few changes to your code. Here is my version:

```
import Control.Monad

-- no need for the do and let
bar :: Num a => a -> IO a
bar x = return $ x + 1 -- or: bar = return . (1+)

-- liftM2 to make (,) work on IO values
test :: Num a => IO a
test = do (x,y) <- liftM2 (,) (bar 10) (bar 20) -- or: (,) <$> bar 10 <*> bar 20
          return y

-- show that this actually works
main :: IO ()
main = test >>= print
```

Your types did not match: your `(bar 10, bar 20)` evaluates to type `Num a => (IO a, IO a)` but you're treating it as `Num a => IO (a, a)`. By lifting `(,)` we're making it work on `IO` values, and returning an `IO` value.

Look at this (GHCi, `import Control.Monad` to get `liftM2`):

```
:t (,)
-- type is :: a -> b -> (a, b)

:t liftM2 (,)
-- type is :: Monad m => m a -> m b -> m (a, b)
```

in our case the `Monad` is the `IO` monad. Thus, the final output of `liftM2 (,)` will work nicely inside the `IO` do-block because it returns a proper `IO` value.

And, of course you could solve this particular problem with the less verbose:

```
test'' = bar 20
```

*PS: Please don't return stuff into the `IO` monad without any reason. You're making perfectly pure operations look unpure and there's no reasonable way back.*

Comment: +1: thanks for rewriting `bar` and further explanations. Functions in question are just a excuse to simplifiy the post, I'm obviously don't put stuff in `IO` monad if not necessary... :)

Answer (score 1):

you will need a helper function to lift the `IO` from inside the tuple
for brevity's sake I will use `Int` instead of  `Num a => a`

```
(bar 1, bar 2) :: (IO Int, IO Int)
```

thus you need something with signature

```
liftTuple :: (IO x, IO y) -> IO (x, y)
liftTuple (mx, my) = ...
```

then you can do the `(x,y) <- liftTuple (bar 1, bar 2)`

Comment: for just extracting the second component of the tuple you can also use `snd`